# collect issue after using pipe operator in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The content of test.py is as follows:

```
def run():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        print line
        print "##"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

and using pipe operator code likes this:

```
sc.addFile("test.py")
t = [1,2,3,4]
t_rdd = sc.parallelize(t)
pipe_rdd = t_rdd.pipe("test.py")
t_rdd.collect()
t_rdd.collect()
```

The result of first collect is `[u'1', u'', u'##', u'2', u'', u'##']`，and the result of second collect is `[u'3', u'', u'##', u'4', u'', u'##']`.

Why collect() cannot return all data? 
The default partitions number of my spark is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice the `import pandas as pd` in test.py. And some nodes in my cluster have not install pandas yet. So the partitions in these nodes do not return value. I found the error log in webUI finally.